# how to get uncommon value's from table 1 and table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just want to retrieve not common value from Table 1 related to Table 2 as i shown in below image. 
How to display uncommon values as i shown in result in below image

this is the query i'm using but its not showing result as i expected

```
select * from t1.* from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 on t1.Name <> t2.Name
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain the logic.  Why is "SQL 2K12" in the result?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name = TableB.name
WHERE TableA.id IS null
OR TableB.id IS null
```

In case of outer join the uncommon rows are not present in other generating a NULL field in each row. We basically select it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
Select col 
 From (
        Select col from Table1
        Union All
        Select col from Table2
      ) A
 Group By col
 Having count(*)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Except` and `Union All`. Not sure why `"SQL 2K12"` is in result because it is present in both the tables

```
select col from table1 
except
select col from table2
Union all
select col from table2 
except
select col from table1
```

Comment: i'm getting Error Message : Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: @user6503334 - How did you replace in your original query. The number of column in select should same also it should type compatible

Answer (score 0):

This is according to your examples

```
SELECT *  -- or SELECT COALESCE(t1.Name,t2.Name) As Name
FROM
    Table1 t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
WHERE
    t1.Name IS NULL OR t2.Name IS NULL;
```

If there is only one column in both tables (or two tables have identical columns) and if you do not want these columns repeated

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Table1   
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM
    Table2

EXCEPT
(
SELECT *
FROM
    Table1
INTERSECT
SELECT *
FROM
    Table2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1  where table1.name not in(select name from table 2)
```